# Pentaho report designer line chart item labels overlap

Tags: pentaho-report-designer

I am new to Pentaho report designer.
I have created a simple line chart in Pentaho report designer.
Whenever two lines on the chart come close to each other or cross each other their labels overlap.
How do I control the positioning of the labels so that they don't overlap. I want labels to be displayed for both lines on the chart. Please see the attached image.[image]